# setting an image as background is not working

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm working on a login form and I want to have an image as background behind the input area. I don't know if it's not working due to the code or because I have done the image in the wrong folder. Atm the image is in the assets folder.

HTML

```
<ion-content class="background">

<ion-card>
 <ion-card-header>
   Login
</ion-card-header>

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" value=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
     <a> Forgot your password? Get help here </a>
     <button ion-button full round color="rank">Register</button>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS

```
  page-home {



    background{
        background-image: url('../assets/login.jpg');
    }

    .button{
        top: 90px;

}

}
```

Comment: maybe should be **../assets/login.jpg**

Comment: This should be `../assets/login.jpg`.

Comment: hmm I changed it thx, but it still doesn't work:(

Comment: This should be `.background{}`

Comment: @TGrif oh nice that worked I really thank you:)